# How to migrate app using sqlite database to Google Cloud. Wants to use (CRUD) all operations on data

Tags: android, sqlite, google-cloud-storage, migrate, google-cloud-platform

I got an app which stores nearly 3 MB data in sqlite. Its working all good  but sqlite stores data in user's device which increase size of the app.

I am using **SQLiteOpenHelper**,**SQLiteDatabase** classes to do `CRUD`(Create,Retrieve,Update,Delete) operations data.

Creating tables and inserting data (`int`,`string`) in it.

Fetching required data using below command.

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DbConstants.table_name,null);
```

**Development Environment:**

`Ubuntu 12.04`

`Android Studio`

`Java`

I am wondering if I could save/insert data in Google's Cloud and do the operations like `select` specific column from table or `delete` data from table and so on which I am currently doing in app.

Will it cost me?

Please give me the useful link or any sample app which can do all CRUD operations on data stored in cloud.

> Edit:
>
> Do I need to change all existing code such as creating Table,insert
>   query, select query to use Google Cloud Storage?

Thanks for your valuable time!
Please help..

Answer (score 3):

I'm also migrating to Google Cloud, this link was very helpful: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

and this library for data treatment: 
https://github.com/objectify/objectify

Comment: Thanks for the links. These are helpful. Did you  migrate your code from sq-lite to Google Cloud?